# How to sign a PDF with a stamp using Mupdf?

Tags: windows, pdf, digital-signature, mupdf

I need to make a software on Windows that can sign a PDF with USBKey which contains a certificate and a stamp image. I need the stamp image show up on the signed PDF and can be checked by common PDF readers like Adobe's. I used mupdf library to render the PDF,but I don't know the  process of signature. Could anybody tell me what functions should I use and how to invoke them?